# Show that the solution of the differential system are periodic.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Let $y,z$ two functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

> Show that the solution of the differential system :
>   $$
> y'=z^3 \qquad z'=-y^3
> $$
>
> are periodic.

My attempt :
With some works I can show that the "path" is included in the curve of equation $y^4+z^4= K$

I can only say that traverses a connected part (image of $\mathbb{R}$ by a function of $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ continuous) of this curve but it does not prove the periodicity because if the image is not a closed, one could never go through the same point on the curve
I tried to eliminate one of the unknown functions.

We have $y''=3z^2z'=-3y^3(K-y^4)^1/2$ but I cannot see how can I do next ? Perhaps one has a direct way to prove the claim ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an autonomous differential system and the solutions stay on a bounded closed curve hence either they converge to a point of the curve when $t\to\infty$ without ever reaching it, or they cycle in the sense that there exists some finite $T$ such that $(y(t+T),z(t+T))=(y(t),z(t))$ for every $t$.

In the present case, the square of the velocity $(y')^2+(z')^2=y^6+z^6$ is uniformly bounded below by a positive constant on each curve $y^4+z^4=c$ with $c\gt0$, hence the solutions cycle.

Comment: Thank you Did(+1), I do not know (or perhaps it splip my mind..)  your first property do you have any reference ?

Comment: If a solution U is such that U(t) and U(s) are distinct for every distinct times t and s, then U cannot trackback on the curve C where it is confined and U cannot either continue to move forever at positive speed on C since C has finite length, hence U must accumulate. On the other hand, if U(t)=U(s) for some t>s then U has period t-s by the uniqueness of the solutions of a dynamical system.

Comment: I got it. Thanks again.

Comment: Is it correct to say that the velocity does not vanish then we do not have turning point (point de rebroussement in French) on this curve and so we went around the curve->the solutions cycle ?

Comment: @Edwin The curves C have no "point de rebroussement" here so the task is rather to show that the solution does not accumulate on a given point of C (and to show that, a shorter argument than the one in my post is that there is no fixed point on C).

Comment: And how can I show that the curves C have no fixed point ? Thank you.

Comment: @Edwin Because the system has no fixed point except (0,0).

Comment: @Did arf yes, you are right. Good eyes.